# Number of possible ways n people can meet for lunch on a circular table such that each day no two people sit together who have sat together before?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

So i started studying this book on graph theory by Nar Singh Deo, and fairly early on the following problem gets introduced:

n people decide to meet for lunch every day, however they decide that they will sit in a manner such that no two same people sit together any of the days.

How many days can this go on?

If we hypothesize a complete graph of order n, and find a set of disjoint Hamiltonian cycles, the cardinality of this set is our answer. (Here, by disjoint Hamiltonian cycles i mean cycles where the edges do not overlap).

If we imagine a circle, with points numbered 1, 2, 3, ... n , and we skip 1, then 2, then 3, etc we will start to find potential answers / potential Hamiltonian paths. However, the path will only be Hamiltonian if we skip by a number k such that gcd(k, n) = 1.  Which means, that the number of potential paths is $\phi(n)$ (which is the Euler Totient function)

I took 9 as an example case, and tried to work it out :

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
1 3 5 7 9 2 4 6 8 
1 5 9 4 8 3 7 2 6 
1 6 2 7 3 8 4 9 5 
1 8 6 4 2 9 7 5 3 
1 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2

So it can be seen that, after the half way point, the paths begin to mirror themselves. The first three cycles satisfy the condition. So the answer = 3 or $\frac{\phi(9)}{2}$. I hypothesized for the answer to be $$\frac{\phi(n)}{2}$$ for an arbitrary n, However, the book gives an answer $$\frac{n-1}{2}$$ if n is odd and $$\frac{n-2}{2}$$ if n is even, which just seems wrong. What am i missing? And what exactly is the relationship between the Euler Totient function and Hamiltonian paths?

Comment: There are many Hamiltonian cycles in the complete graph which are not created by skipping a constant number of vertices around a circle each time. In fact, since the graph is complete, ANY permutation of your vertices forms a Hamiltonian cycle.

Comment: ah yes, you are right.The sequence 1 7 9 5 8 3 6 2 4 1 is also an example of a possible arrangement, i missed it was in the book. So then how to derive the (n-1)/2 if odd and (n-2)/2 if even ?

Comment: i just noticed in the example i just stated 9 and 5 are sitting together so my confusion has heightened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case $n$ is even: see [Number of edge disjoint Hamiltonian cycles in a complete graph with even number of vertices.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/881420/5676)

Case $n$ is odd: see [Hamiltonian Cycle Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/194247/5676)