# Factorization in Hamiltonian graphs

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Show that for any integer $n \geq 0$, the complete graph with $2n + 1$ vertices can be $2$−factorable into $n$ Hamiltonian cycles

A graph $G$ is 2-factorable if and only if it is 2r-regular for some r.

If $G$ is Hamiltonian, then that $G$ has a $2$-factor.

I'm trying by induction but I have problems with the inductive step.

Comment: Does https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194247/hamiltonian-cycle-problem answer your question?

Comment: Are you still here?

Comment: yes, thank you  :3

Comment: No copien¡¡¡¡¡¡¡

Comment: Please, Lmath, don't vandalize your question. You can flag it for moderator attention to be closed as a duplicate, if you want.