Can the edges of the complete digraph with $n$ vertices (and therefore $n(n-1)$ edges) be partitioned into $n$ Hamiltonian paths?
I believe this may be true when $n = 2^k$ or when $n$ is $1$ or even. I have checked manually for $n=1,2,4,8$; I know it is impossible for $n=3$; and I have tried and so far failed to find solutions for $n=5, 6, 7$.
Edit: what about partitioning into $n-1$ Hamiltonian cycles? I think these problems may be equivalent.

Regarding the edit: I think the problems are not equivalent. Consider the case of $n=3$. OP stated that this case in the original problem (Hamiltonian paths) has no solution (I agree); however, it does have a solution for the Hamiltonian cycle problem. (Just pick any Hamiltonian cycle, and there is a full Hamiltonian cycle available in the other direction.)

Those two problems are not equivalent. For $n=3$ we can partition the edges into $2$ Hamiltonian cycles but we cannot partition the edges into $3$ Hamiltonian paths.

Good spot, thank you

@Amogh They are not equivalent for a particular $n$, but they are equivalent as a whole. This is because $\vec K_n$ can be partitioned into directed Hamiltonian paths if and only if $\vec K_{n+1}$ can be partitioned into directed Hamiltonian cycles.

@MikeEarnest Oh, I see

Check out this related problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/194247/hamiltonian-cycle-problem?rq=1

I think you'd be interested in Tony Huynh's answer in https://mathoverflow.net/a/197783

@MathieuRundström thank you. So $K^_{n+1}$ can be decomposed into cycles for $n+1 \neq 4, 6$, meaning (per @MikeEarnest) $K^_n$ can be decomposed into paths for $n \neq 3,5$.

Let $\vec K_n$ be the complete directed graph on $n$ vertices. This lemma shows that the path version of your problem is equivalent to the cycle version.
Lemma: $\vec K_n$ can be partitioned into Hamiltonian paths if and only if $\vec K_{n+1}$ can be partitioned into Hamiltonian cycles.
Proof sketch: Given a partition of $\vec K_n$ into Hamiltonian paths, adjoin a new vertex, and close each path a to a loop by connecting the end of each path to the new vertex, and connecting the new vertex to the start of each path (it is not immediately obvious, but is also not hard to prove, that this covers each edge in and out of the new vertex exactly once). Conversely, given a partition of $\vec K_{n+1}$ into Hamiltonian cycles, delete a vertex, so that each cycle gets two edges deleted and becomes a Hamiltonian path on the remaining vertices. $\square$
From now on, I only consider the cycle version.
When $n$ is odd, the undirected $K_n$ can be partitioned into Hamiltonian cycles. See Wikipedia for the method, which  is attributed to Welecki. You first partition $K_{n-1}$ into Hamiltonian paths, as shown here, and then close up each path into a cycle with a new vertex. Therefore, the directed $\vec K_n$ can be partitioned as well, using two oppositely oriented copies of each loop in the undirected solution.
When $n$ is even, it turns out the Hamiltonian cycle decomposition is impossible for $n\in \{4,6\}$, but it is possible for all even $n\ge 8$. This was proved by Tillson in 1980.

Timothy W Tillson, A Hamiltonian decomposition of K2m*, 2m ≥ 8,
Journal of Combinatorial Theory, Series B,
Volume 29, Issue 1,
1980,
Pages 68-74,
https://doi.org/10.1016/0095-8956(80)90044-1.

